# Change CKAN Resource URL Max Length

Tags: ckan

Can we change max character length for ckan resource url?
[URL Resource in CKAN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYgHS.png)

Notes: my team is adding data using API url directly that's why they need longer url. If you have better method please do tell, very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there are no restrictions on resource's URL field(except for the PostgreSQL's text type).

For example, that's how you can create a resource with a "URL" that consists of 2000 `a`(using [ckanapi](https://github.com/ckan/ckanapi)):

```
ckanapi action resource_create \
    package_id=statistics-contact \
    url=$(head -c 2000 < /dev/zero | tr '\0' 'a')
```

If you want to set the upper bound on the maximum allowed length for URL, you have to [customize resource's schema](http://docs.ckan.org/en/2.9/extensions/adding-custom-fields.html#adding-custom-fields-to-resources)(or use [ckanext-scheming](https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-scheming)).